# Displaying directions from JSON Information

Tags: ios, iphone, json, google-maps, directions

I have implemented Google Maps API for iOS. I have successfully loaded the map and dropped two pins on it. I also have implemented the Google Maps Directions API, and I got the Json response. I don't know how to decode that and show directions on the map.

Here is the code:

In the direction.h

```
-(void)retrieveDirectionsFromOrigin:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)origin toDestination:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)destination
{
    NSString *directionsURL=[NSString                stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/json?   origin=%f,%f&destination=%f,%f&sensor=false",origin.latitude,origin.longitude,destination.longitude,destination.longitude];
    _directionsURL=[NSURL URLWithString:directionsURL];
    [self retrieveDirections:nil withDelegate:self];
}

-(void)retrieveDirections:(SEL)selector withDelegate:(id)delegate{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:_directionsURL];
    [self fetchedData:data withDelegate:delegate];
});
}

-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)data withDelegate:(id)delegate{
NSError* error;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSLog(@"Directions %@",json);
}
```

In the MapViewController.h

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

// Creates a marker in the center of the map.
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
GMSMarker *marker2 = [[GMSMarker alloc]init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(21.422492, 39.826169);
marker2.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(21.413333, 39.893333);
marker.map = mapView;
marker2.map = mapView;
directions=[[Directions alloc]init];
[directions retrieveDirectionsFromOrigin:marker.position toDestination:marker2.position];
[mapViewView setNeedsDisplay];
[mapView setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

Please let me know what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

When your Directions API returns results, it places them within a (JSON) routes array. This route may consist of one or more legs depending on whether any waypoints were specified. Each route within the routes field may contain the following fields:

- legs[] contains array that holds information about a leg of the
  route, between two locations within the given route. A separate leg
  will be present for each waypoint or destination specified. Each leg 
  consists of a series of steps.
- overview_polyline contains array of encoded points that represent an
  approximate path of the resulting directions.

**Legs:**
Each element in the legs array specifies a single leg of the journey from the origin to the destination in the calculated route.

- steps[] contains an array of steps denoting information about each
  separate step of the leg of the journey.
- start_location contains the latitude/longitude coordinates of the
  origin of this leg.
- end_location contains the latitude/longitude coordinates of the given
  destination of this leg.

**Steps:**
Each element in the steps array defines a single step of the calculated directions. A step is the most atomic unit of a direction's route, 
containing a single step describing a specific, single instruction on the journey. E.g. "Turn left at W. 4th St."

**Next step:**
Now that you have converted your json to NSDictionary, use the key's above to get each leg long/lat and apply a GMSPolygon object on the map which dispaly a custom path of each leg.